# Get the Date format from the Java code

Tags: java, timestamp

I want this date format YYYY-MM-DD.

Please help me on this :

```
java.util.Date date= new java.util.Date();
Timestamp time = new Timestamp(date.getTime()); 
System.out.println(time);
```

Comment: Did you even *try* to search for `java date format`???

Answer (score 1):

This should help you:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
    String time = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(date);
    System.out.println(time);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it with the help of SimpleDateFormat class or simply use Joda's LocalDate.

```
String dateInString= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH).format(date);
System.out.println(dateInString);
```

Using Joda

```
System.out.println(LocalDate.now().toString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
```

Comment: you have a little mistake delete " , " from "yyyy-MM-dd", , Locale

Comment: oops thanks mate, corrected